# Assume that $G \subseteq A$ is open in $(X, d) .$ Show that $G$ is open in $\left(A, d_{A}\right) .$

Tags: real-analysis

This problem comes from Spaces: An Introduction to Real Analysis by Tom L. Lindstrøm. Chapter 3.3 P8. The full description is as follows,

8. Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and let $A$ be a subset of $X$. We shall consider $A$ with the subset metric $d_{A}$.
   a) Assume that $G \subseteq A$ is open in $(X, d) .$ Show that $G$ is open in $\left(A, d_{A}\right)$.
   b) Find an example which shows that although $G \subseteq A$ is open in $\left(A, d_{A}\right)$ it need not be open in $\left(X, d_{X}\right)$.
   c) Show that if $A$ is an open set in $\left(X, d_{X}\right)$, then a subset $G$ of $A$ is open in $\left(A, d_{A}\right)$ if and only if it is open in $\left(X, d_{X}\right)$

I don't quite understand what the problem want me to prove. For (a), if we let $X = \mathbb{R}, d(x,y) = 0 \text{ when } x=y \text{ and } d(x,y) = 1 \text{ when } x\neq y, A = [0,5],d_A(x,y) = |x-y|, G = [1,2]$. It is easy to see that G is open in $(X,d)$ but closed in $(A,d_A)$, which contradicts with what the problem wants me to prove. What's the problem here? Did I miss anything?

Comment: The subset metric $d_A$ is defined by $d_X(a,b)=d(a,b)$. It is just the restriction of the metric on $X$ to $A$.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have another question. What does it mean by open in $(X,d)$ and open in $(A,d_A)$? What's the difference between them?

Comment: $A$ is always open in $(A,d_A)$, whether or not $A$ is open in $(X,d)$.

Comment: Thank you Kavi, I think this makes it all clear.